# How do you handle large JSON files with Cron Jobs, without editing php.ini?

Tags: php, json, cron

Many retailer APIs send very large files, and I frequently run into memory allocation barriers. Two examples are Walmart Clearance, and the entire Best Buy catalog which contains files as large as 272 MB.

Without increasing the memory in php.ini,  and primarily using Cron Jobs, what is the best way to parse these large files?

Answer (score 1):

What follows is a terrible idea... but in leui of any other ideas:

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit','300M');
// ...stuff...
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

If you *have* to do it this way, keep it in a cron job, preferably don't even run it on the same machine as your web server.